# RasPi not reachable from Android phone

Tags: connection, android, lighttpd

I've been strugling with this problem for quite some time now, and i'm at my wit's end. I don't even have any idea what i could try to be looking for.

I have a raspi running with raspbian lite and lighttpd in my home LAN.

IP is obtained automatically and is currently at 192.168.1.3
I can connect to it per laptop (win10) and two desktop PCs (win7 & 10) with no problem at all.

The problem is, when i try to connect via my phone (Chrome on Samsung GS7E, Android 7.0, same result with "Samsung Internet"), i can not connect most of the time (though not always. there are days where i can connect without a problem...).
The Browser says

`This site can't be reached.
http://192.168.1.3/ is unreachable.
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`

I have tried everything i can to find out why. restarted router/raspi numerous times, tried removing other devices from the network, different browsers on my phone. i tried remote debugging to see if there is any kind of information in the network tab, but i can't find ANYTHING and it makes absolutely no sense to me... Windows: works, Android: doesn't work.

I can also connect over PuTTy from windows.
JuiceSSH over Android: `no Route to Host`

They are 100% on the same network, IP:port is 100% correct.

What are possible reasons for this behavior? how can it even exist in the first place? and how can i repair it? what are options/places i can check to see why this happens??

## EDIT

ifconfig @ raspi
https://i.stack.imgur.com/26uNS.png

LAN devices overview @ router (Alice Box 6641)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXQ5B.png

WIFI devices @ router
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eptVC.png  (1.5 = Laptop (working), 1.6 = Android (not working))

please note: i have LAN AND WIFI activated on the raspi. LAN is automatic IP, WIFI is static at .1.244 neither of those are accessible from android. both are from laptop

Comment: Your question is lacking info, example IP adr. of PC, Android. And include all network details like, IP adr., subnetmask and gateway.

Comment: i have added some screenshots, please feel free to ask if you need more specific info

Comment: Adding pictures is counter productive, when the same can be pasted in as text!

Comment: What I understand with your infos: the raspi has ethernet and wifi enabled. Windows can reach raspi through ethernet and wifi. Smartphone cannot reach ethernet and wifi on raspi. Is there a LAN cable between Windows PC and raspi? Smartphone has no ethernet connection, right? It can only connect through wifi. Seems there is a problem with primary network device and routing on raspi. Suggest for testing to turn off ethernet on raspi.